# Mongo query with regex fails when backslash\newline is there in a field

Tags: mongodb, symfony

Hi I have a field in a user collection called "Address".User saving their address from a textarea in my application. mongodb convert it to new line like following.

```
  {
   "_id": ObjectId("56a9ba0ffbe0856d4f8b456d"),
   "address": "HOUSE NO. 3157,\r\nSECTOR 50-D",
   "pincode": "",
   },
{
   "_id": ObjectId("56a9ba0ffbe0856d4f8b456d"),
   "address": "HOUSE NO. 3257,\r\nSECTOR 50-C",
   "pincode": "",
   }
```

So now When I am running a search query on the basis of "address".Like following:

```
guardianAdd = $dm->getRepository('EduStudentBundle:GuardianAddress')->findBy(array(
                'address' => new \MongoRegex('/.*' .$data['address'] . '.*/i'),
                'isDelete' => false
            ));
            echo count($guardianAdd);die;
```

it does not give any result. My Searchi key word is : "HOUSE NO.3157 SECTOR 50-D".

However if I am searching using like: HOUSE NO. 3157 its giving correct result.

Please advice how to fix this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, trailing `.*` are redundant. regexps `/.*aaa.*/` and `/aaa/` are identical and match the same pattern.

Second, you probably need to use multiline modifier `/pattern/im`

Finally, it is not quite clear what you want to fix. The best think you can do is to provide some basic explanation of regex syntax in the search form, so users can search properly, e.g. `HOUSE NO.*3157.*SECTOR 50-D` to get best results.

You can make some bold assumptions and build the pattern with something like

```
$pattern = implode('\W+',preg_split('/\W+/', $data['address']))
```

which will give you a regexp `HOUSE\W+NO\W+3157\W+SECTOR\W+50\W+D` for different kind of `HOUSE NO.3157 SECTOR 50-D` requests, but it will cut all the regex flexibility available with bare input, and eventually will result with unexpected response anyway. You can follow this slippery slope and end up with your own query DSL to compile to regex, but I doubt it can be any better or more convenient than pure regex. It will be more error prone for sure.

Asking right question to get right answers is true not only on SO, but also in your application. Unfortunately there is no general solution to search for something that people have in mind, but fail to ask. I believe that in your particular case [best code is no code](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-best-code-is-no-code-at-all/).

Comment: $pattern = implode('\W+',preg_split('/\W+/', $data['address']));


 $guardianAdd = $dm->getRepository('EduStudentBundle:GuardianAddress')->findBy(array(
                    'address' => new \MongoRegex('/.*' .$pattern . '.*/i'),
                    'isDelete' => false
                ));
Still I am not getting result..

Comment: Actually, User can input full address or half address to search. I am not able to get a good solution for this.